# Cannot see Anaconda navigator in start menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda on my "Windows 10 Enterpirse 2016 LTSB" a year ago. It was working fine in the Windows command prompt and Anaconda prompt.

Two weeks ago, I tried to install TensorFlow 2.0, but it gave me an error. So I decided to uninstall Anaconda and re-install it again, which was a big mistake. I followed the installation instructions step by step in [Anaconda official website.](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/windows/), but after the installation, I couldn't see "Anaconda Navigator" nor "Anaconda prompt" [in the Windows start menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08NKU.png)

Although, I can see Anaconda [ِin the installed programs in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmazq.png), and I can navigate to the installation folder:["C:\Users\AP90350\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ZbY.png), but "conda" command does not work at all.

I uninstalled and re-installed with different options, also I tried to add the installation path to "Windows paths" but with no avail, nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used pip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to:

1. Uninstall anaconda and all Python distribution
2. In the rood drive of the Windows e.g., "C:\" search for "*conda* and delete any file or folder with that name.
3. Reinstall Anaconda